# Java 2D game: Where to put "global" non-final variables

Tags: java, swing, variables, static, global

I am working on a Java 2D game for which I am using AWT graphics, a JFrame and a JPanel. I would like to know where I should store some non-final but globally accessible (I need to be able to read/change these variables from every other Object/Class) variables to coordinate e.g. the width and height of the game's panel, which I want to be able to change in a little settings menu within the game.

At the moment, I am storing these variables in a separate interface which most of my other classes implement, but this means I cannot change the variables as they are all final.

As I see it I have two options:

Put all these variables as static, non-final ones in my main game class and access them via `Game.PanelWidth`

OR

Create a separate class just for these variables and access them like this: `Variables.PanelWidth`, where "Variables" would be that new class' name.

Which method is better, or should I use a completely different approach?

Comment: We don't know how your game/program classes look like for full & thorough  consideration. Secondly, you already answered your question, but my two cents: if you work with multi-threading environment, don't forget to consider `volatile` identifier.

Comment: Take a look at the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  Just be careful if you're multithreading to properly synchronize access to the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going through your code, it's hard to provide a specific response.

## General recommendations:

> At the moment, I am storing these variables in a separate interface which most of my other classes implement, but this means I cannot change the variables as they are all final.

It's not a good idea to use inheritance to access your settings. For this reason alone I think either of the options you're considering is an improvement as it uses composition instead of inheritance.

You should consider applying the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

- Who is responsible for managing your game's settings? Maybe a `Properties` object.
- Who is responsible for constructing such an object? Maybe the `main` method.

If you apply this principle, hardly any of your classes should require access to the `PanelWidth` property.

## Specific recommendations:

Java provides a [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class. This class is both thread safe and easy to use when loading/storing properties to files.

From the Javadoc:

> This class is thread-safe: multiple threads can share a single Properties object without the need for external synchronization.

Rather than creating a static properties object, consider constructing the properties object in the `main` method (basically, poor-man's dependency injection)

Answer (score 1):

The choice is largely up to you and should be driven by a balance between complexity and the actual needs of the application.

The interface you mentioned is a known anti-pattern **Constant Interface** - generally frowned upon because you litter the inheritance tree and namespace everywhere with information that should remain encapsulated. It does work though and in small projects it may be acceptable.

A separate class is a better approach, it solves at least the namespace litter. Make its constructor final to prevent accidental subclassing.

Generally, static members can work in small projects, but it can turn out to be impossible in case the project grows and it turns out that the variables aren't really application global, but only use-case global. Refactoring such a case can create a lot of work later.

Using an actual instance of the "global" settings class prevents this from the start, the cost is that you need to pass the instance around to where it needs to be accessed (e.g. as constructor parameter).

Next is threading and the issue of communicating *changes* to those global variables. Unless your application is running in a *single* thread (that would be the case in a purely event driven swing application), you cannot simply make changes to values and expect the change to take effect *properly* at every dependency site (imagine just having read panelWidth, but before you can read panelHeight new dimensions are set). You need a way to prevent these situations. So simple members are out. You'll want get/set methods that ensure only complete information is read and that writes of related values are atomic.

The atomicity can be ensured by encapsulating related values into a composite object, e.g.: Instead of panelWidth, panelHeight you have a panelDimension. No getters/setters for the individual values, are provided. You can only get the entire Dimension (for reads) or replace it with a new dimension (for writes). The actual member can be either volatile, of the AtomicReference variety or protected by making getter/setter synchronized.

To properly communicate changes to every dependency site, you may need some notification mechanism, so either the entire global state or individual parts of it may need the ability to register listeners and notify those listeners on changes (again threading issues are to be considered, since listener callbacks are usually implemented on the thread making the change, which may need consideration in the listener called).